# Symfony & Twig: Custom exception_controller not working on production

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, twig

I'm trying to setup custom error pages in a Symfony 3.4 project. What I have so far is custom error templates in standard location: `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` and they work fine.

I now I'm trying to go a step further and use custom ExceptionController to provide the templates with custom params.

1. I created more elaborate custom error templates expecting more params.
2. I made a custom subclass extending ExceptionController with `showAction()` method providing the params.
3. I added `exception_controller: 'AppBundle:Exception:show'` key to twig in `app/config/config.yaml`.

It works fine when I use custom error path `/app_dev.php/_error/404` but when I enter a wrong path on production it bypasses my custom `ExceptionController` completely and falls back to the custom error templates.

It looks as if the `exception_controller` setting is being ignored in twig config and I have no idea why. Is there anything missing in the config?

Comment: In `2` you say you created the function `showAction`, yet in `3` you configured `AppBundle:Exception:show`. Can you try using the complete function name `AppBundle:Exception:showAction` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that earlier (as in Symfony docs) but there was error during cache:clear saying that there is no method showActionAction so I decided that the format should be similar as in routing where you omit the Action part (at least in Symfony 3.4)

Comment: Tried again: `The controller for URI "/_error/404" is not callable. Expected method "showActionAction" on class "AppBundle\Controller\ExceptionController". Available methods: "__construct", "showAction".`